# SSL implementation for selected asp pages in Windows server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I have a asp based website on windows server 2008. I would like to make some selected pages as SSL (https).

I tried to enable https. But when i try to access using http it gives error. how to enable https only for selected pages on a website?

Thanks

-Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean ASP 3.0 (Classic ASP) and not ASP.NET, I ran into this a while back myself and basically Microsoft's HOW TO is the best solution:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239875

Comment: Hi Nissan. Thanks for the response. i tried this solution. for non https pages it gives this error. The page you are trying to access is secured with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).

Comment: Make sure you exit the SSL pages to URLs which are absolutely pathed to http or create a non-SSL include which does a redirect in a similar fashion to the SSL redirect.  It's a pain, but ASP 3.0 always was.

Comment: any other easy way? i have some 10000 files out of which i have some 100 files to be secured with ssl. and there are over 200 links on each page that are relative.

Answer (score 0):

It is frequently good security practice to require Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) for certain pages on a Web site. **Although this can be configured through the Internet Services Manager (ISM) in the Microsoft Management Console (MMC),** you can also use Active Server Pages (ASP) to force SSL for specific pages without making changes in the MMC.

is it possible to do for selected pages in iis?